# Rattling noise while clutch disengaged / car in neutral

Tags: clutch, noise, saturn

I recently bought a Saturn Ion with a manual transmission.

Today I noticed the following noise during driving: while the clutch is disengaged (pedal pushed down) and also while the car is in neutral (in this case it doesn't matter if the clutch pedal is pushed down or not) I hear a rattling / pulsating sound (from the front of the car) with the intervals between the rattlings corresponding to the speed in which the car is currently rolling (the slower the car rolls the less frequent I hear the rattling). When the car stands, I hear nothing - independent of the clutch being (dis-)engaged or the car being out of gear or not. Otherwise everything seems fine - changing gears is ok, etc. - no noise or cracks while changing gears or while driving or while accelerating or braking.

What might be broken? Do I have to change the clutch, or is this a minor problem?